# Why is riverpod failing even to initialize in project? Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

So i am trying to get started with riverpod and creating a new flutter project with the "click and counter" default sample.
As soon as I add on the pubspec

```
flutter_hooks: ^0.18.0
hooks_riverpod: ^2.0.0
```

And

> import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

I get this error on the debug console and can't figure it out what is the problem

```
: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
../…/framework/provider_base.dart:904
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(error, chain);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
../…/framework/provider_base.dart:898
Never _rethrowProviderError(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^
```

Comment: Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh The fact is that i have written zero code. Just created a new flutter project in VSCode and it starts with the template of a counter app which works just fine in emulator and device. as soon as I install riverpod as mentioned in their docs that error shows up and I can't find where it comes from. No extra dependencies or code added. Also tried with a flutter clean and pub get and still nothing I can track to see where the error comes from. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Error.throwWithStackTrace` was added in Dart 2.16 (Flutter version 2.10 from Feb 8, 2022).

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Error/throwWithStackTrace.html

(Check the `@Since` annotation.)

If your Flutter/Dart version is below that, you'll get the error you saw.

Two options that *may* help are:

1. Specify an exact version of dependencies (don't use `^` ahead of version)
2. upgrade Flutter/Dart to at least 2.10/2.16

```
flutter upgrade
```

If your problematic package (`hooks_riverpod: ^2.0.0` in your case) is listed with `^`, it'll [use the latest version that doesn't break dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53563080/2301224).

I'm guessing that when you created a new project and used that same dependency version, upon initial `pub get` it downloaded a newer version of the package (***or*** a newer version of a dependency that that package uses) into "pub cache" which is relying on the new Error API method.

Your project will store this information in:

```
<your_project_dir>/dart_tool/package_config.json
```

The `min Dart SDK` version listed for the package should normally have changed from 2.12 to 2.16. (update: it's [been updated now](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/8184))  This would give us a hint that we need to update our Flutter/Dart if we see our build failing.

In an earlier version of this answer, I noted that the `^` prefix on package dependency versions is supposed to prevent these types of issues, but I'm no longer certain it was meant to cover this situation where the underlying platform needs to be updated (as opposed to a breaking change in the API of the package itself).

Anyways, at first glance, it might make sense to go from 2.0.0 to 3.0.0 for a package version # when it depends on a new core Dart API method that did not exist when 2.0.0 was published.

###### Notes

The author of riverpod also wrote the new API for `Error.throwWithStackTrace` so likely the latest version of hooks_riverpod is using the latest API changes. (The version you're listing 2.0.0 is pre-release currently).  You could try earlier versions of riverpod in your pubspec.yaml (such as 1.0.3)

Comment: flutter upgrade worked for me. I was using 2.8.1 and upgraded to 2.10.2

Comment: Thanks, exactly what was happening. It sure seemed like an "error" on their part, but I am more likely to make mistakes

Answer (score 3):

for anyone facing " Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace' " with firebase.
try to add this to your pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67869719).

How about trying `flutter pub upgrade`?

If it is not resolved, then check `analyzer` version and check which dependency locks that.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [Baker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259018/), `Error.throwWithStackTrace` was recently added in Dart 2.16.

If you're getting an error about `Error.throwWithStackTrace` not being found for some package, the package author neglected to update their package's minimum Dart SDK version.  You should report that to the package maintainer.  In the meantime, you should use an earlier version of the problematic package or use a newer version of the Dart SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try running flutter upgrade

By this it will upgrade your flutter and dart SDK version and hope it resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

if you are still facing the issues after "flutter upgrade" or you use this line of code in pubspec.yaml

```
  dependency_overrides:   
    firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
```

you receive this type of errors

```
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitMethodDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1066)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
```

so Try to upgrade your gradle version, this line in your build.gradle

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

after doing that it may be possible it ask you to change your
gradle-wrapper.properties

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

to

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

also upgarde this packages

```
firebase_core: ^1.10.0
firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0
```