# Flutter - Problem with adding Firebase Messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.19042.1348], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

My pubsec.yaml has only:
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.1
firebase_core: ^1.2.1
flutter_local_notifications: ^6.1.0

The problem I am having even on a brand new Flutter Project is that I am getting the following error when I add import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart'; to main.dart

```
/D:/Flutter/flutter_windows_2.5.0-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:13:11: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Flutter/flutter_windows_2.5.0-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:16:9: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Flutter/flutter_windows_2.5.0-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:11:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Flutter\flutter_windows_2.5.0-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\flutter_windows_2.5.0-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: `firebase_messaging` depends on `firebase_messaging_platform_interface` which [just](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/8156) got updated to version `3.2.0` which now depends on Dart 2.16 from Flutter 2.10. [Details on issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259018/2301224) (also affected `riverpod` so very similar).  In case upgrading to Flutter 2.10 causes build failures, [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71273383/2301224).

Comment: Try to compare your pub.yml file if you want to use for web https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_web/pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 14):

[Error.throwWithStackTrace](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Error/throwWithStackTrace.html) was added in Dart 2.16 (Flutter version 2.10 from Feb 8, 2022).

You should either:

- Update Flutter to 2.10: `flutter upgrade`
- Or use older version of conflicting package: `firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6`

Comment: Follow this issue for updates: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/8181

Answer (score 11):

Tried all of the proposals, here and in the link here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/8181

But only that worked for me

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
  firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface: 3.1.13
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: 5.4.13
  firebase_auth_platform_interface: 6.1.11
  firebase_storage_platform_interface: 4.0.14
  cloud_functions_platform_interface: 5.0.21
  firebase_analytics_platform_interface: 3.0.5
  firebase_remote_config_platform_interface: 1.0.5
  firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface: 0.2.0+5
  firebase_performance_platform_interface: 0.1.0+5
  firebase_app_installations_platform_interface: 0.1.0+6
```

This are the dependencies I am using in first place

```
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.2.1
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.9
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.0
```

Comment: yes, dependency_overrides. i spent three days just wondering why this happened

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem and got a workaround for this.

Add firebase_messaging_platform_interface pubspeck.yaml:

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
```

Answer (score 3):

There were changes made to the dependencies of the Flutter Firebase packages
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/8156

You can either update to use `>=2.16` version of dart
Or override the dependencies, you only need to add the ones that you are using

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
  firebase_storage_platform_interface: 4.0.14
  cloud_functions_platform_interface: 5.0.21
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: 5.4.13
  firebase_auth_platform_interface: 6.1.11
  firebase_database_platform_interface: 0.2.0+5
```

Answer (score 2):

So I ran into this problem recently while using **firebase_storage**

What I did to solve the problem was... (I was on flutter 2.6 and dart 2.14).

Upgrade flutter and dart version: Into terminal, run `flutter upgrade` or in my case, `flutter upgrade --force`, since flutter upgrade was giving me some issues.
Then I added the latest version of the dependencies to my pubspec (firebase_storage_10.2.0)
At this stage, running the app will likely throw an error about unsupported compileSDKVersion or so, and ask you to upgrade.
For that, go into your app level build.gradle file

> ("project"\android\app\build.gradle),

and under android, change the compileSDKVersion from it's current value to what flutter asks you to change to. in my case, it was from 30 to 31

```
android{
       //change compile sdk version to 31 (in my case. flutter will tell you which version you should set to)
       compileSdkVersion 31
}
```

When you run the app now, it will check for licenses for the Android SDK Package you just edited (31). it should automatically accept and install everything neccessary.
Flutter run might then fail again, with the error of an incompatible kotlin version, and that you should update or so.
To update the kotlin version, go to the project level build.gradle **("project"/android/build.gradle)**
change the kotlin version here **(ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.5')** to the latest version which can be found [Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#targeting-the-jvm). as of now, the latest version is 1.6.10
so this line of code now reads

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

Now you are good to go. run the app again, it might take much longer than usual, but it should work just fine.
Or at least it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was obtaining the following error:

> {flutter-folder}/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.2.9/lib/src/internals.dart:11:20:
> Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.   return
> internals.guardWebExceptions(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I recently solved it adding firebase_messaging_web: 2.2.7 to my dependency_overrides section

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_web: 2.2.7
```

You can see the package available versions at https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging_web/versions

**flutter --version**

```
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git<
Framework • revision 097d3313d8 (10 days ago) • 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
Engine • revision a83ed0e5e3
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

**pubspec.yml**

```
dependencies:
  firebase_messaging: 10.0.9
```

I hope you find this usefull. I was facing this problem for a long time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I updated the comment. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This [throwWithStackTrace method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Error/throwWithStackTrace.html) was added in flutter's dart-core since 2.16 flutter version.
The workaround would be adding the dependency_overrides just like how we add

```
dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

and

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

now we have to add dependency overrides in the same manner as dependencies and dev_dependencies. Example:

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
  firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface: 3.1.13
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: 5.4.13
  firebase_auth_platform_interface: 6.1.11
  firebase_storage_platform_interface: 4.0.14
  cloud_functions_platform_interface: 5.0.21
  firebase_analytics_platform_interface: 3.0.5
  firebase_remote_config_platform_interface: 1.0.5
  firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface: 0.2.0+5  
  firebase_performance_platform_interface: 0.1.0+5 
  firebase_app_installations_platform_interface: 0.1.0+6
```

Reference: [Issue created in flutter's github](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/8181)

Answer (score 0):

Add into yaml:

```
 firebase_messaging_platform_interface
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do this simply**

*One Line Answer: Upgrade all the packages using your terminal*

Step 1:
List out all the outdated packages: "flutter pub outdated" (in terminal)

Step 2:
Upgrade the packages: "flutter pub upgrade --major-versions" (in terminal)

**It helped me, I hope it will apply the same to you**

Answer (score -2):

As suggested in this post([how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug)) you should try to run in your terminal "Packages get | Pub get" and then build the project again