# Flutter app running on web failing with error:

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

> **/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.2.8/lib/src/internals.dart:11:10:
> Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.   return
> internals.guardWebExceptions(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:13:11:

> Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
> Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:16:9:

> Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
> Error.throwWithStackTrace(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:11:7:

> Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never'
> doesn't allow null. Never convertPlatformException(Object exception,
> StackTrace stackTrace) {
> ^ Failed to compile application.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Problem with adding Firebase Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71259801/flutter-problem-with-adding-firebase-messaging)

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution for this.

I added it to my **pubspeck.yaml:**

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
```

Have a good day :)

Answer (score 8):

There were changes made to the dependencies of the Flutter Firebase packages
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/8156

You can either update to use 2.16.0 version of dart or newer.
Or override the dependencies, you only need to add the ones that you are using

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
  firebase_storage_platform_interface: 4.0.14
  cloud_functions_platform_interface: 5.0.21
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: 5.4.13
  firebase_auth_platform_interface: 6.1.11
  firebase_database_platform_interface: 0.2.0+5
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work by running `flutter upgrade` and adding:
`dependency_overrides: cloud_firestore_web: 2.6.5`

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out earlier by [GarrettBarlocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6917847/garrett-barlocker), dependency overrides of all the firebase dependencies used in my project did the trick for me and it solved the problem.

Don't try flutter upgrade as it upgrades your project to the latest version of the flutter release. And it will force you to migrate your project to android v2 embedding as v1 embedding is deprecated in flutter 2.10.2 thereby failing to compile and build the application. Also, you may face compatibility issues with other dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and got a workaround for this.

override firebase_messaging_platform_interface in pubspeck.yaml:

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
```

check ref: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/8181

Answer (score 0):

remove the firebase ^9.0.2 from  the pubspec.yaml file
because this partucular one is for Web apps and  you're trying to build an android app