# Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'. return internals.guardWebExceptions

Tags: flutter, error-handling, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, build-error

I am getting the below error while I am running the flutter run , If anyone can help that will be very helpful for me.
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_web-3.2.9/lib/src/utils/errors.dart:20:20: Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.
return internals.guardWebExceptions(

I have tried adding firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6 as override.
Also, tried adding the below dependenices:
dependency_overrides:
firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
firebase_storage_platform_interface: 4.0.14
cloud_functions_platform_interface: 5.0.21
cloud_firestore_platform_interface: 5.4.13
firebase_auth_platform_interface: 6.1.11
firebase_database_platform_interface: 0.2.0+5
The above does not work.
If anyone can let me know how to fix that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem, I updated firebase_core version to 1.13.0 and then it worked

Answer (score 5):

`flutter pub upgrade` works for me. This is already discussed over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71261321/flutter-app-running-on-web-failing-with-error)

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to `firebase_core: ^1.13.1` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your all firebase packages to the latest version