# "Error: Member not found" with Flutter Firebase Auth package

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
 /Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
 Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.

Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
   ^
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

My pubsec.yaml has only:

- cloud_firestore:
- firebase_core:
- uuid:
- firebase_auth: ^3.3.8
- provider: ^6.0.2

I got this error after importing firebase packages.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.6.0-12.0.pre.657, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1526], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: add specific version code to firebase_core and cloud_firestore , like this `firebase_core: 1.13.1` .consider using  all latest firebase package

Comment: `firebase` now has dependencies using Dart 2.16.  [Similar issue & solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259018/2301224)

Answer (score 6):

For me.
upgrading flutter resolved the issue.
`flutter upgrade`

Comment: this and I had to add this
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
end

Answer (score 4):

I tried using latest version but It didn't worked.
Lower version   `firebase_auth: 2.0.0` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

`firebase` now has dependencies using Dart 2.16. [Similar issue & solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251830/why-is-riverpod-failing-even-to-initialize-in-project-method-not-found-error/71259018#71259018)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. So I updated my flutter version(2.2.2) to a newer version(2.10.4) and it resolved the issue.