# execution issue in Mac M1 chip nut not in windows OS

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, flutter-dependencies

my project was execute properly at both platform suddenly i add one dependency it was fail to build, i was remove and try again to build project but issue was still occurs  when i run  it's throw error like :

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[38495]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1f7d378f0) and ?? (0x1165342b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[38495]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1f7d37940) and ?? (0x116534308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/Flutter Project/New/Weone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:694:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
              (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/Flutter Project/New/Weone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:626:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning
        int best_offset;
                       ^
                        = 0
    1 warning generated.
    1 warning generated.
    4 warnings generated.
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/Flutter Project/New/Weone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:694:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
              (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/Flutter Project/New/Weone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:626:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning
        int best_offset;
                       ^
                        = 0
    1 warning generated.
    35 warnings generated.
    35 warnings generated.
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadataExif.m:9:9: warning: non-portable path to file '"SYMetadataExif.h"'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
    #import "SYMetadataEXIF.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            "SYMetadataExif.h"
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadataExif.m:41:65: warning: 'kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeOrginal' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - No longer supported [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                 SYStringSel(subsecTimeOriginal):       (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeOrginal,
                                                                    ^
    In module 'ImageIO' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadataExif.m:10:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Headers/CGImageProperties.h:248:34: note: 'kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeOrginal' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    IMAGEIO_EXTERN const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeOrginal IMAGEIO_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(10.4, 10.11, 4.0, 10.0);
                                     ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:49:36: warning: 'ALAsset' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    + (instancetype)metadataWithAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
                                       ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:40:12: note: 'ALAsset' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface ALAsset : NSObject {
               ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:52:5: warning: 'ALAssetRepresentation' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetRepresentation.h:20:12: note: 'ALAssetRepresentation' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface ALAssetRepresentation : NSObject {
               ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:52:52: warning: 'defaultRepresentation' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                                                       ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:49:1: note: 'defaultRepresentation' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (ALAssetRepresentation *)defaultRepresentation AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead");
    ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:53:57: warning: 'metadata' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex() to retrieve metadata from an image returned by the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        return [self metadataWithDictionary:[representation metadata]];
                                                            ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetRepresentation.h:56:1: note: 'metadata' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (NSDictionary *)metadata AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex() to retrieve metadata from an image returned by the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead");
    ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:150:13: warning: 'ALAsset' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        __block ALAsset *assetAtUrl = nil;
                ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:40:12: note: 'ALAsset' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface ALAsset : NSObject {
               ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:151:5: warning: 'ALAssetsLibrary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetsLibrary.h:78:12: note: 'ALAssetsLibrary' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface ALAssetsLibrary : NSObject {
               ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:151:50: warning: 'ALAssetsLibrary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                                                     ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetsLibrary.h:78:12: note: 'ALAssetsLibrary' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface ALAssetsLibrary : NSObject {
               ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:154:49: warning: 'ALAsset' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                                    ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:40:12: note: 'ALAsset' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface ALAsset : NSObject {
               ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:154:14: warning: 'assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: on PHAsset to fetch assets by local identifier (or to lookup PHAssets by a previously known ALAssetPropertyAssetURL use fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:) from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                 ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetsLibrary.h:93:1: note: 'assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (void)assetForURL:(NSURL *)assetURL resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)resultBlock failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: on PHAsset to fetch assets by local identifier (or to lookup PHAssets by a previously known ALAssetPropertyAssetURL use fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:) from the Photos framework instead");
    ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:165:5: warning: 'ALAssetRepresentation' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [assetAtUrl defaultRepresentation];
        ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetRepresentation.h:20:12: note: 'ALAssetRepresentation' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface ALAssetRepresentation : NSObject {
               ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:165:57: warning: 'defaultRepresentation' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [assetAtUrl defaultRepresentation];
                                                            ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:49:1: note: 'defaultRepresentation' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (ALAssetRepresentation *)defaultRepresentation AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead");
    ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:166:28: warning: 'metadata' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex() to retrieve metadata from an image returned by the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        return [representation metadata];
                               ^
    In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetRepresentation.h:56:1: note: 'metadata' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (NSDictionary *)metadata AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex() to retrieve metadata from an image returned by the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead");
    ^
    12 warnings generated.
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:39:18: warning: direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior [-Wobjc-string-compare]
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:39:18: note: use 'isEqual:' instead
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^~
           [          isEqual:       ]
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:82:18: warning: direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior [-Wobjc-string-compare]
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:82:18: note: use 'isEqual:' instead
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^~
           [          isEqual:       ]
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:109:16: warning: unused variable 'swf' [-Wunused-variable]
        const char swf[3] = {'F', 'W', 'S'};
                   ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:110:16: warning: unused variable 'swc' [-Wunused-variable]
        const char swc[3] = {'C', 'W', 'S'};
                   ^
    4 warnings generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    12 warnings generated.
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:39:18: warning: direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior [-Wobjc-string-compare]
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:39:18: note: use 'isEqual:' instead
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^~
           [          isEqual:       ]
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:82:18: warning: direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior [-Wobjc-string-compare]
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:82:18: note: use 'isEqual:' instead
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^~
           [          isEqual:       ]
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:109:16: warning: unused variable 'swf' [-Wunused-variable]
        const char swf[3] = {'F', 'W', 'S'};
                   ^
    /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.1.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:110:16: warning: unused variable 'swc' [-Wunused-variable]
        const char swc[3] = {'C', 'W', 'S'};
                   ^
    4 warnings generated.
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:13:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
        Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:16:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
      Error.throwWithStackTrace(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:11:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
    Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
          ^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
        Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
      Error.throwWithStackTrace(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
    Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
          ^
    Failed to package /Users/techeniacservices/Documents/Flutter Project/New/Weone.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
```

in pubspact.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
  ...
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.6
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6 
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.2.0
  ...
```

i try to clean project, pub get, delete all pod file, rebuild project, restart IDE etc

i also checkout my committed branch and try to run but sill on that code also occur same issue.
can anyone help me to solve this...

Thank you

Comment: Firebase is now depending on Dart 2.16 API and its new `Error` static method.  [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259018/2301224) with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

update flutter

- 2.10.3

```
dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.0
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.5 
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in pubspec.yaml file -

```
dependencies:
  platform: ^3.1.0
```

and run -

```
flutter pub get
```