# Flutter/Gradle Not Building After Initializing Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle

I've just configured Firebase for use with my app, and now when I try to build, Gradle throws me an error. I've tried deleting pubspec.lock and running pub get, and I have not seen any errors in my code. Does anyone know what might be causing [this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1qLc.png)

Any and all help is appreciated. TIA :)

Comment: please run flutter doctor , then show the out put

Comment: @JintoJoseph Here is my output: https://imgur.com/ocdvkQn

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to just comment...
Please check this answer [Why is riverpod failing even to initialize in project? Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251830/why-is-riverpod-failing-even-to-initialize-in-project-method-not-found-error)
and see if upgrade Flutter/Dart to at least 2.10/2.16 solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### You might have to run `flutter clean` so it deletes your pubspec lock file and the build folder

Then you run `flutter pub get to get depencies`

#### The error might also be coming from your firebase configuration. Crosscheck it again

In the `android/app/build.gralde` file

make sure that your `minSdKVersion` is >= 21. It is very important when you add some Firebase packages

make sure you have multidexEnable set to true